# MongoDB and Phalcon API

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

I am trying to connect mongoDB with phalcon API framework. 
My code is like below :

index.php file

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('include/models')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (preg_match('/\.php$/', $entry)) {
            require_once "include/models/$entry";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);    
}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

$app = new Phalcon\Mvc\Micro();
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
$config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini('include/config/config.ini');

// Simple database connection to localhost
$di->set('mongo', function() {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    return $manager->selectDb("MyApi");
},true);

$di->set('collectionManager', function () {
    return new Phalcon\Mvc\Collection\Manager();
});
$app->setDI($di);


$directory = new User_detail();


 $app->get('/userdetail/{code}', function ($code) use ($app,$directory) {
   $directory->getUser($app,$code);
  });

 $app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
   $app->response->setStatusCode(424, "Method Failed")->sendHeaders();
   echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'messages' => "Method Failed"));
});
$app->handle();
?>
```

Model file User_detail.php

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Collection;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\Db\Column;

class User_detail extends Collection
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource("User");
    }

    function getUser($app,$code)
    {
            $robot = User_detail::findFirst(
                [
                    [
                        "Name" => "android",
                    ]
                ]
            );

            echo $robot->Name; die;

    }
}
?>
```

I am getting error as

> Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::selectDb() in
>   index.php

What is wrong in it?

Comment: Your error tells you that the method `selectDb` doesn't exist in the class `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`. If you open that class you'll see that the method doesn't exist there... thus giving you the error.

Comment: Thank you!!! Do you have any idea of it, which function is used to select database?

Comment: If I am not mistaken use: `$manager = new MongoClient(); return $manager->selectDB("MyApi");`. Check the documentation: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/odm.html#setting-a-connection. But if you are using PHP7, you should indeed use the phalcon incubator: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter

Answer (score 2):

First I installed Phalcon incubator using composer into my vendor directory:

```
composer require phalcon/incubator
```

Then I make sure that vendor libraries are loaded:

```
include_once SITE_ROOT . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then I use \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\MongoDB\Client() found in  vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter/MongoDB/Client.php

In services.php:

```
$di->setShared('mongo', function () use ($config) {
    $mongo = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\MongoDB\Client();
    return $mongo->selectDatabase($config->mongodb->dbname);
});
```

Then ensure my MongoCollection extends \Phalcon\Mvc\MongoCollection (vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/MongoCollection.php).

models/MyCollectionStats.php:

```
<?php

namespace Common\Models;

class MyCollectionStats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\MongoCollection
{...
```

Answer (score 0):

For php7 you need to use MongoCollection and other related classes from incubator.

Comment: Can you please give some example or reference link for it.

Comment: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator
https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/blob/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/MongoCollection.php
https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter